# Can't Get Selected Item from Dropdownlist for Controller Method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to both AngularJs and MVC.  I am trying to get related records for a company when the company is selected in a dropdown list using AngularJS and MVC.  I am populating the dropdown list, but when a company is selected, the event to get related records never fires.  Here is my Angular Controller:

```
myApp.controller("CompanyController", 
function($scope, $timeout, companyService)
{
    getCompanies();
    function getCompanies() {
        companyService.getCompanies()
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.companies = data;
            })
         .error(function (error) {
             $scope.status = 'Unable to load customer data: ' + error.message;
         });
    };


    $scope.getCurrentModules = function(){
        companyId = $scope.company;
        companyService.getCurrentModules(companyId)
        .success(function (data){
            $scope.data =data;
        });

    }

});
```

Here is my Angular Service:

```
angular.module('dashboardManagement')
```

.service('companyService', [
    '$http', function ($http) {

```
    this.getCompanies = function () {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetAllCompanies');
    };

    this.getCurrentModules = function (id) {
        return $http.get('/Home/GetCurrentModules?id=' + id);

    };
}
```

]);

Here is my MVC View:

```
            <td>
            Please Select an Operator:<br />
            <br />
            <div id="companyContainer">
                <div ng-controller="CompanyController">
                    <select id="CompanySelector" data-ng-model="company" data-ng-change="getCurrentModules()">
                        <option ng-repeat="company in companies" value="{{company.CompanyID}}">{{company.vchCompanyName}}</option>
                    </select>
                    <br />
                    You selected: {{company}}
                </div>
           </div>
        </td>
```

Here is my MVC Controller:

```
        [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public JsonResult GetCurrentModules(int companyId)
    {
       // throw new NotImplementedException();
        var modules =  this._operatorDashboardRepository.GetWithStoredProcedure("scGetDashboardModulesByWidgetID @WidgetID", "companyId");

        var moduleList = modules.OrderBy(module => module.vchRankingWidgetModuleHeaderText);

        return Json(moduleList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?  I placed a break in the MVC Controller to see if the "GetCurrentModules" ever fires, but it does not.  Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: i dont think `$http.get` will call a `[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]` action  change it to `[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]`

Comment: Thanks for your help, but changing it to HttpGet did not make the method fire still.

Comment: you're also passing in a parameter of id in `return $http.get('/Home/GetCurrentModules?id=' + id);` but your action is expecting parameter `companyId`   change it to `$http.get('/Home/GetCurrentModules?companyId=' + id);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1

Change your `getCurrentModules` method to use `$http.post` instead of `$http.get`.  Also make sure your parameter names match

```
return $http.post('/Home/GetCurrentModules?companyId=' + id);
public JsonResult GetCurrentModules(int companyId)
```

Option 2

Change your `JsonResult` to allow `HttpGet`

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetCurrentModules(int companyId)
```

again make sure parameter names match